# How to get created time of record in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, timestamp

I have a problem with data in Oracle database:

I want to get created time of some record in table. I can get ora_rowscn of the record, but I cannot run to change this ora_rowscn to timestamp by query SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ora_rowscn) because SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP() may not be available for older data (my data was inserted about 1 month ago).
Anyone have solution to resolve this problem for me to get created time?

Comment: If your table or application didn't have some kind of auditing built in, there likely isn't anything you can do now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best thing to do here, assuming you have a long term need for this requirement, would be to alter your current table and add a bona-fide timestamp column.  You could give this timestamp column a default value of the current timestamp, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    ...
    created_time TIMESTAMP(6) default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Then, when inserting a new record, omit mention of the `created_time` column, letting Oracle back fill it with the current timestamp.